# Regex expression in java remove first value in csv

Tags: java, regex

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
12,2014-10-09 06:00:00,2014-10-09 06:15:00,"","","","123,456","","9,999","",""
```

I was able to replace the comma inbetween the digits and all double quoutes using:

```
String test = rowData.replaceAll("([0-9]),([0-9])","$1$2").replaceAll("\"","");
```

I'm not sure if this is the best approach to do this (opinion is appreciatted). My problem is I need to remove the first value before the comma also, so basically my output needs to be something like this

```
Orig: 12,2014-10-09 06:00:00,2014-10-09 06:15:00,"","","","123,456","","9,999","",""
Need: 2014-10-09 06:00:00,2014-10-09 06:15:00,,,,123456,,9999,,
```

I'm not sure if another regex is needed to do this as I don't know how exactly or use something like lastindex or firstindex to remove the fist value of the comma??? thank you

EDIT: I just noticed I can't use ([0-9]),([0-9]) cause it also remove the comma for the datetime. :(. Proper question is how to replace the csv to remove the:
1. first value
2. quotes
3. comma between the digit and quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match your expected output you can do something like

```
String str = "12,2014-10-09 06:00:00,2014-10-09 "
    + "06:15:00,\"\",\"\",\"\",\"123,456\",\"\",\"9,999\",\"\",\"\"";
str = str.substring(str.indexOf(',') + 1);
str = str.replaceAll("\"(\\d+),(\\d+)\"", "$1$2").replace("\"", "");
String expected = "2014-10-09 06:00:00,2014-10-09 06:15:00,,,,123456,,9999,,";
System.out.println(str.equals(expected));
```

Output is

```
true
```

Comment: Thank you. I also have a digit with 2 comma ,"999,999,999", so I just added an extra line str = str.replaceAll("\"(\\d+),(\\d+),(\\d+)\"", "$1$2$3");. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String test = rowData.replaceAll("^[^,]+|,(?!(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$|\"(?=,)|(?<=,)\"", "");
```

There are three alternations that are replaced with blank (ie removed):

- everything up to and including the first comma
- all commas within quotes (those not followed by an even number of quotes)
- all quotes adjacent to (immediately after or before) commas

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 test = test.substring(test.indexOf(",") + 1, test.length());
```

Reasons this is better than the other guys answer: less overhead, no need for regex for this!